# How was saturation current found? Was it assumed in this question?

Tags: bjt, saturation, common-emitter

I'm just a really confused about how Saturation current, Is,  was either solved/derived or assumed?? Please see images of question and solution. The question requires that you find all the bias resisitors from the design requirements given.

Thanks

[image: Question]
[image: Solution]

Comment: On the 4th Line, where Vbe= VT(ln(Ic/Is)). How was Is determined?

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, false alarm. The saturation current and Beta values have already been stated at the beginning of the question sheet.